# About initialization in Objective C iPhoneSDK

Tags: objective-c, ios4, initialization

I have a problem with the initialization of two objects. I have:

```
banner = [[UIBannerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIBannerViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"Banner: %@", banner);
homeBanner = [[UIBannerViewController alloc] initWithBanner:vistine];
NSLog(@"HomeBanner: %@", homeBanner);
```

Inside the UIBannerViewController I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
if ( !isInitialized ) {
    bannerViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    // DEPRECATED
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadDataFromInternet) 
                             toTarget:self 
                           withObject:nil];
} else {
    // TODO: Questo non va più bene qua.
    // [pageControl setNumberOfPages:[images count]];
    [pageControl setNumberOfPages:[bannerViews count]];
    [pageControl setCurrentPage:0];
}
```

No matter what I do: if I uncomment the following code snippet

```
bannerViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    // DEPRECATED
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadDataFromInternet) 
                             toTarget:self 
                           withObject:nil];
```

the App crashes with Exception: *** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array.
What is/can be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use an autorelease NSMutable array 
`[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0]`

Comment: Well, it's seems that the method: performSelectorOnMainThread sends his messages to every object... This causes the crash.